# How to merge two icon (FontAwesome) .ttf files and then extract just the icons needed

Tags: nativescript, truetype

I'm surprised this is turning out to be so difficult; it's so simple in concept.

I use a variety of FontAwesome icons in my NativeScript app.  With FontAwesome 4 these were all in a single file. With FontAwesome 5 the icons have been split into multiple files, and I now need some of the icons that are new to v5.  What I want to do is combine two of the FontAwesome .ttf files, then extract just the icons I need to make a much smaller .ttf file.

I've spent the afternoon investigating this.  What I find keeps pointing me to FontForge, but I can't get sfddif to work.  For example:

```
[~/Documents/NativeScriptProjects/cyclenc/app/fonts]$ /Applications/FontForge.app/Contents/Resources/opt/local/bin/sfddiff  --usage
-bash: /Applications/FontForge.app/Contents/Resources/opt/local/bin/sfddiff: /Users/travis/build/fontforge/fontforge/build/osx/FontForge.app/Contents/Resou: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I open a single font file with FontForge I get warning messages that the icons have been remapped to different code points, so that's no good.

Is there a way to easily combine two .ttf files?  TransType just creates duplicates of the .ttf files, and RoboFont won't even open - it dies with a flash of a window that's loading resources.  I'm doing this on a Mac but can switch to Windows if needed.

As far as the extract goes, it appears that `[https://everythingfonts.com/subsetter][1]` can handle that part nicely, if I can ever get the merged pair created.